# Dynamic pivot table or what?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a table that consists of pageno int, groupid varchar(10). Each row in the table is distinct. There can be multiple groupid and pageno combinations. The amount of pagenos is unknown and the amount of groupids is unknown. The data might look like this:

```
pageno groupid
101105 mpadilla
101105 gentry
100100 mpadilla
100100 gentry
```

I would like to have a result set returned that shows the pagenos as columns and the groupids as rows and an x where they intersect (meaning it exists for that pageno/groupid combo).

Would I use sql pivot for this? If so, give me an example please. If not, please provide your example and explanation. I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not entirely clear but if I am understanding your question you can use the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the result.

The basic syntax for this query of query would be the following if you had a limited number of `pagenos`:

```
select groupid, [101105], [100100]
from
(
  select pageno, groupid, 
    flag = 'X'
  from yourtable
) d
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for pageno in ([101105], [100100])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1578a/3).

Then if you have an unknown number of values, you will need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(pageno) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by pageno
                    order by pageno
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT groupid, ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select pageno, groupid, 
                flag = ''X''
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for pageno in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1578a/1).  Both versions will give a result:

```
|  GROUPID | 100100 | 101105 |
|   gentry |      X |      X |
| mpadilla |      X |      X |
|     test |      X | (null) |
```

Edit, if you have nulls that you want to replace, then I would create a second list of column names this one will be used for the final select list and it will include `coalesce` to replace the null.  The code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsNull AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(pageno) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by pageno
                    order by pageno
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsNull = STUFF((SELECT ', coalesce(' + QUOTENAME(pageno) +', '''') as '+QUOTENAME(pageno)
                    from yourtable
                    group by pageno
                    order by pageno
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT groupid, ' + @colsNull + ' 
            from 
            (
              select pageno, groupid, 
                flag = ''X''
              from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for pageno in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1578a/2). The result will be:

```
|  GROUPID | 100100 | 101105 |
|   gentry |      X |      X |
| mpadilla |      X |      X |
|     test |      X |        |
```

Comment: Thank you bluefeet. It's very similar to what I ended up with. Can you view my code and expand on it possibly? I want to know now how to change the NULLS to either empty or some other text to make the results easier to read. Right now I have MANY NULLS and it's cluttering the results.

Comment: @user2766661 see my edit, you will create a second column list that will be used to replace the nulls

Comment: Thank you bluefeet but I'm a little confused on how to translate your code into mine. Can you look at my code and give me an example from that on how to use coalesce. I've been looking at many examples besides yours and I still can't get it to work with my code. See my code below where I answered my initial question. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried again and got it with your help bluefeet. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I answered my own question. What I did was add an additional column called customized to my original table. This column only contains an x for each customized page. Kind of redundant I know but it seems that the pivot table needs 3 columns. So here is my dynamic code that I came up with and works:

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000), @groupids VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @groupids = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT 
    '],[' + LTRIM(groupid) 
    FROM DistinctPages 
    ORDER BY '],[' + LTRIM(groupid)
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1,2, '') + ']'   
SET @query =
'SELECT * FROM (SELECT pageno, groupid, customized FROM DistinctPages)t
PIVOT (MAX(customized) FOR groupid
IN ('+@groupids+')) AS CustomizedPagesPerGroups'
EXECUTE (@query)
```